# Tiny Video Network

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

According to [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.06961):
[image]

```
import torch as t

class TinyVideoNetwork(t.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TinyVideoNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.conv2d_1 = t.nn.Conv2d(3, 32, (3, 3))

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv2d_1(x)
        print(x.shape)

net = TinyVideoNetwork()

video = t.empty(6, 3, 72, 128).normal_()

net(video)
```

> torch.Size([6, 32, 70, 126])

To which dimension should we apply `1D pool` from `Block 1`?